# Is this any number?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

*Inspired (like 2 others) by [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38713104#38713104) chat message. (and to some extent, my [CMC](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38713335#38713335))*

Given a string as an input, your task is to check whether or not that string is a number.

### What is a number?

This is a list of all input formats that are "numbers":

- Integers: An integer is a string made entirely of characters from `1234567890`, without any other character e.g. `152`
- Floats: A float is a integer with 1 (no more, no less) decimal points (`.`) in the middle of the number. A decimal point must always be preceded and followed by a number e.g. `1.0` or `3.14`
- Complex: A complex number is a number that follows the format `a+bj` where `a` and `b` are numerical values. The plus sign can also be a minus sign e.g. `1+10j` or `143-1j`. If it saves bytes (or you want to), you may use `i` instead of `j`.
- Longs: A long is any number that would be classed as an integer or a float, with an `L` at the end e.g `1325963L`
- Hexadecimal: A hexadecimal number is a number which consists entirely of characters in `1234567890abcdef`. Upper case characters are valid hex, but only when used consistently e.g. `10a` or `afa` not `A5c`
- Scientific: A scientific number is a number which consists of a run of digits (`1234567890.`) followed by an `e` followed by a run of digits, optionally preceded by a `-`. A `E` may also be used.

Any of these 5 may also be preceded by a minus sign (`-`) but any whitespace in the number causes it to no longer be a number e.g.  `-3.5 + 2i` isn't a number. Longs may not be hexadecimal but may be floats

You must output 2 distinct values (preferably truthy and falsy but you may choose) for inputs that are either numbers as defined above, or not.

### Test Cases

These should result in truthy

```
10
-9.34
-3.5+2j
ab1
100000L
3.14159L
-73e-7
7E53C80
1.2e3
12E3.4
```

And these should be falsy

```
abcdefghijklmnop
10.10.10
2569LL
10L+9j
8+45io
4aE3
3.
.3
```

Now because small numbers are easier to work with, this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code, *in bytes*, wins!

Comment: Isn't `4E3` = 4000?

Comment: I don't downvote, but I find these rules (only lowercase `e`, `j` and not `i`, single `L` is OK) quite arbitrary. This reads basically "design me a regex for this spec".

Comment: It seems exceedingly inconvenient to only allow the use of `j` rather than either `i` or `j`, so long as convention is internally consistent within the answer - as I would be willing to bet there is at least one language in which `i` is used to denote complex numbers - beyond this, I am aware of at least 20 languages in which `E` is the proper notation for scientific notation - by preventing this internal method of interpretation seems like it would artificially inflate some answers

Comment: @Uriel I have changed it so that the rules are less rigid about input, and have changed the appropriate test cases.

Comment: I think that you could add another couple of hex numbers to clarify the changes you made i would suggest something like `7EC80000` as truthy (to show that you may not assume the letters `a-fA-F` wiil not always be in a single block)

Comment: @TaylorScott it is. Read the part on floats again.

Comment: @dzaima thanks for catching all that, clarified

Comment: `Upper case characters are valid hex` that mean that we have to support both all-lowercase and all-uppercase hexadecimal, right?

Comment: @dzaima you may choose

Answer (score 4):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>53</s> <s>52</s> 50 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
O[►~hΘP█⁵\↔<sK⁹>¼⅝┘d⁾Δo≡7ξδ¾▓↑ΧGj4<eu╝t┼Pπ»‘øβ!d!-
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=TyU1QiV1MjVCQSU3RWgldTAzOThQJXUyNTg4JXUyMDc1JTVDJXUyMTk0JTNDc0sldTIwNzklM0UlQkMldTIxNUQldTI1MThkJXUyMDdFJXUwMzk0byV1MjI2MTcldTAzQkUldTAzQjQlQkUldTI1OTMldTIxOTEldTAzQTdHajQlM0NldSV1MjU1RHQldTI1M0NQJXUwM0MwJUJCJXUyMDE4JUY4JXUwM0IyJTIxZCUyMS0_,inputs=LTMuNSsyag__) or [test all test cases](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=LiU3QiUyQyUzQURUQG8lMjJPJTVCJXUyNUJBJTdFaCV1MDM5OFAldTI1ODgldTIwNzUlNUMldTIxOTQlM0NzSyV1MjA3OSUzRSVCQyV1MjE1RCV1MjUxOGQldTIwN0UldTAzOTRvJXUyMjYxNyV1MDNCRSV1MDNCNCVCRSV1MjU5MyV1MjE5MSV1MDNBN0dqNCUzQ2V1JXUyNTVEdCV1MjUzQ1AldTAzQzAlQkIldTIwMTglRjgldTAzQjIlMjFkJTIxLW8_,inputs=MjElMEExMCUwQS02NCUwQS05LjMzJTBBLTMuNSsyaiUwQTMrNWolMEFBQjElMEExMDAwMDBMJTBBMy4xNDE1OUwlMEEtNzNlLTclMEE3RTUzQzgwJTBBMS4yZTMlMEExMmUzLjQlMEElMEFhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wJTBBMTAuMTAuMTAlMEEyNTY5TEwlMEExMEwrOWolMEE4KzQ1aW8lMEE0YUUzJTBBMy4lMEEuMw__) (first number indicates amount of test cases)

based on a regex - `^(-?\d+((\.\d+|)(L|e-?\d+(\.\d+|)|\+\d+(\.\d+|)j|)|)|[A-F\d]+)$`

Comment: Not sure this works for `−3.5+2j` or `ab1`

Comment: the first one uses a unicode dash, [which shouldn't be](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38813347#38813347) (and has been fixed in the examples), and for the second - this expects all uppercase hexadecimal

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>72</s> <s>71</s> 65 bytes

*saved one byte thanks to @Cowsquack*
*saved 6 bytes thanks to @dzaima*

```
a=>/^(-?\d+((\.\d+|)(L|e-?\d+(\.\d+|)|\+\d+(\.\d+|)j|)|)|[A-F\d]+)$/.test(a)
```

JS port of @dzaima's answer. Credit to @dzaima for the regex.

Comment: `/regex here/.test(a)` is shorter than `match`

Comment: you don't need the `==null` if you use test

Comment: Fails for lowercase hexadecimals.

Comment: @darrylyeo caird said in the comments that you can choose whether to support lowercase or uppercase hexadecimals

Comment: Can you simply use `/regex here/.test`, eliminating `a=>` and `(a)`? I'm not a Javascript programmer, but this seems to me like it would work

Comment: @musicman523 it has to be either a full program or a function, not a snippet

Comment: Would that not return a function?

Comment: @musicman523 according to my Chrome console, doing something like `f=/a/.test` and then trying to call `f("a")` causes `Uncaught TypeError: Method RegExp.prototype.test called on incompatible receiver undefined`. So technically, it returns a function, but it's one that doesn't work...

Comment: Huh, weird. I don't know anything about JS so I can't help you there

Comment: you need to bind it on `/a/`, which loses the byte savings

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>290</s> <s>136</s> 105 bytes

Python port of @dzaima's answer. All credit to @dzaima for the regex :)

```python
lambda s:re.match('^(-?\d+((\.\d+|)(L|e-?\d+(\.\d+|)|\+\d+(\.\d+|)j|)|)|[A-F\d]+|[a-f\d]+)$',s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3daoQwEIXv5ymCLJiQJmyM1lUopRR7lTcwu5Bd4xrrH@pNwXe32bYXHQbOnA/OmelrbcZB7vWL3jvTXyuDlny2vDfrrcHhBbNXXVGMNfeyEaw2@0v@wKbpP9d6QLbyjX3o6ky30rD6cZBD@LQQcP00ziua7V6PM3LIDSgIAhBHYBmXMTDJExq1YK7Cw8cokFzEIskUsFRalkJaJPL9dATBIytBRIXksQ/cKlvfG9d@dv0wTj7Nfxai5DlTyntFsxZONE7cCLEppC8GLsH/L0XOxJkvU@dWHOohJDmaZjesuMaOkP0b)

Comment: You don't need to account for both lowercase and uppercase hexadecimal (caird said that in the comments)

Comment: You don't need to compile the regex.

Comment: [111 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3RaoQwEEXf5yuCFExIEzZG6yqUUop9yh/oLsQ11lg1or4U/HebbfvQYeDOPXDvzF9b5yZ5tM/VMeixbjRa89q5AS@Gj3q7dTi8YvZSNRTjinvZCVa7@SV/YK/oP9d7QPbylb1XzYXupWbt/SAP4eNKCNhxdsuGFnO0bkEW2QkFQQDiBCzjMgYmeUKjHnQtPLyPAslFLJJMAUulYSmkRSLfzicQPDISRFRIHvvArTHtR2f7z2Gc3OzT/GchSp4ypbxXNOvhTOPEOoh1IX0xcAn@fylyJi58nQe74bCaQpKjebHThltsCTm@AQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @totallyhuman thanks! I don't think it needs bool() though, because the re match object is truthy.

Comment: It's 1 byte shorter as `re.compile('...').match` rather than `lambda s:re.match('...',s)`